# Add doubles from a textfile into an array list

Tags: java

I have a textfile that has hundreds of doubles, all separated by commas and I am trying to write a method to get each of the doubles into an array list of doubles. Here's my code:

```
public void ReadFile(String inputfile) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File myFile = new File(inputfile);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(myFile);
    try {
        while (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
            int i = 0;
            arraylist.add(sc.useDelimiter(","));
            i++;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

The trouble I am having is with the line `arraylist.add(sc.useDelimiter(","))'`
I get an error saying "The method add(Double) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (Scanner)". I am unsure of what to do to fix this. Any help?

Comment: It means that it is expecting a `double` or perhaps `Double` as parameter, but you have given it a `Scanner` instead. Try `sc.useDelimiter(",").nextDouble()` or something of that sort.

Comment: You need to re-read the Scanner API because that's not how you use it. Set the delimiter **once** and then call the `hasNextXxx()` / `nextXxx()` method pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Hovercraft said you need to set the delimiter once and move it up to where you initialized the scanner. It should look like this:

```
public void ReadFile(String inputfile) throws FileNotFoundException {

File myFile = new File(inputfile);
Scanner sc = new Scanner(myFile);
List<double> doublelist = new ArrayList<Double>();
//this is where you set the delimiter
sc.useDelimiter(",")
    try {
        while (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
            doublelist.add(sc.nextDouble());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the `useDelimiter` outside of loop. You have to also call `nextDouble` to iterate the numbers in the file.

```
   public static List<Double> readFile(String inputfile) throws FileNotFoundException{
        List<Double> arraylist = new ArrayList<Double>();
        File myFile = new File(inputfile);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(myFile);
        sc.useDelimiter(",");
        try {
            while (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
                Double number = sc.nextDouble();
                arraylist.add(number);
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
        sc.close();
        return arraylist;
    }
```

Also please follow proper naming convention in Java. A method name should start with a lower case letter.